# use of different ImageViews makes scrolling not smooth

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll, imageview, scrollview

I have two layouts :

first ( just 1 or 2 images ) :

```
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
     <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/one"
                />
        </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/one"
                />
        </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/one"
                />
        </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/one"
                />
        </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

second (contains more images) :

```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
     <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/one"
                />
        </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/two"
                />
        </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/three"
                />
        </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/four"
                />
        </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

when I run the second one on my phone it doesn't scroll smoothly.
What is the problem? I saw a lot of apps with more images but they don't lack like this?
and 2 gifs that shows something like I mean :

Mine : http://wstaw.org/m/2015/10/02/my-scroll.gif

Goal : http://wstaw.org/m/2015/10/02/google-scroll.gif

Comment: try checking size of your images and if u can reduce

Comment: they are about 50 kb. I'm planing to add about 200 images of this size so I can't play with the size :(.

Comment: 50 kb is fine, i think u need to check ur java code

Comment: I didn't edit any java, just running these on an empty activity of android studio. is this normal?